# dealing with immediate offsets when moving instruction to fill the branch delay slot in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

Some of the MIPS instructions have immediate offsets.
For example, while moving `lw` command to fill the branch delay slot below the `beq`, its immediate offset changes from 100 to 96.

```
PC     Loop: lw $2, 100($3)
PC+4         addi $3, $3, 4
PC+8         beq  $3, $4, Loop
```

transformed into

```
PC   Loop: addi $3, $3, 4
PC+4       beq $3, $4, Loop
PC+8       lw $2, 96($3) # branch delay slot
```

Is it because PC is always PC+4, so it goes as 100 - 8 + 4 = 96 ? 
What happens if instruction is moving up?
For example,

```
PC       Loop: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
PC+4           addi $5, 4($5)
```

Will this be correct?

```
PC       Loop: addi $5, 4($5)
PC+4           xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change in the immediate has nothing to do with the PC.

```
Loop: lw $2, 100($3)
      addi $3, $3, 4
      beq  $3, $4, Loop
```

In the original you are loading from address ($3 + 100), then adding 4 to $3.

```
Loop: addi $3, $3, 4
      beq $3, $4, Loop
      lw $2, 96($3) # branch delay slot
```

In the transformed one, you are adding 4 to $3, then loading from address ($3 + 96) = (original_$3 + 4 + 96) = (original_$3 + 100). It's the reordering between `lw` and `addi` which affects the immediate (`addi` cannot be moved to the delay slot because the branch depends on the new value of $3).